# Pig java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: jobsInProgress exception

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

I am using pig-0.11.0+28 with CDH4 and when I run any Pig job I get this exception. I also happens in local mode.  Any ideas?

```
2013-07-08 13:53:44,035 [main] WARN  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop23.PigJobControl - falling back to default JobControl (not using hadoop 0.23 ?)
  java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: jobsInProgress
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Class.java:1938)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop23.PigJobControl.<clinit>(PigJobControl.java:58)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.shims.HadoopShims.newJobControl(HadoopShims.java:102)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler.compile(JobControlCompiler.java:285)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher.launchPig(MapReduceLauncher.java:177)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.launchPlan(PigServer.java:1266)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.executeCompiledLogicalPlan(PigServer.java:1251)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.execute(PigServer.java:1241)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.executeBatch(PigServer.java:335)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.executeBatch(GruntParser.java:137)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:198)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:170)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.exec(Grunt.java:84)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:604)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:157)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:208)
```

Comment: You may try to build Pig against Hadoop Yarn (`ant jar-withouthadoop -Dhadoopversion=23`)

Comment: This is a warning. You can ignore it. When Pig detects a low version of hadoop, it will print this warning and switch to use some low APIs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This WARN is harmless at runtime.

Pig is designed to work with a lot of versions.

Since CDH4 ships Apache Hadoop 2.x with an MR1 (0.20/1.x) MR framework option, Pig here is getting confused on what to expect. It detects a 2.x version and tries to load an MR2-style submitter, but if you use MR1, then it would print this noisy WARN and fall back to MR1 and still proceed successfully. The error is followed by a message as or similar to `org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop23.PigJobControl - falling back to default` indicating this.